# Wireless adapter stopped working after kernel update to 4.15

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, Linux 4.15.0-29-generic (x86_64) :
I have a usb wifi adapter (old computer), described as such when I type "lsusb":

```
ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
```

It has been working fine for some time now with Realtek 8812AU driver I installed thanks to this source : https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Yet since last kernel update, I can't use this particular code anymore, because when I try to reinstall it I get several error messages such as:

```
error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer
[-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
init_timer(ptimer);
```

Anyway, I found other sources for the driver, for example this one, https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au, which apparently allowed me to install the module 8812au. Here's what I get whith "modinfo 8812au":

```
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.20_16317.20160108
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     A8D21A7CF2BB805A2609818
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           8812au
vermagic:       4.15.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_rfkfree_enable:int
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_beamform_cap:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_switch_usb_mode:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_dml:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_dc_backoff:DC backoff for Adaptivity (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_th_l2h_ini:TH_L2H_ini for Adaptivity (int)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_th_edcca_hl_diff:TH_EDCCA_HL_diff for Adaptivity (int)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_GLNA_type:default init value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_OffEfuseMask:default open Efuse Mask value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_kfree:default kfree config value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_pll_ref_clk_sel:force pll_ref_clk_sel, 0xF:use autoload value (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
```

I tried several times, rebooted after the installation, plugged in the wifi adapter and nothing ever happens... and I wonder. Any ideas ? Thank you very much.

Edit: Here's the output for `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: enp2s0
       version: 03
       numéro de série: 90:e6:ba:9d:8d:81
       taille: 10Mbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       ressources: irq:19 portE/S:c800(taille=256) mémoire:f6fff000-f6ffffff mémoire:f6ff8000-f6ffbfff mémoire:fbcf0000-fbcfffff
```

Comment: I have virtually the same set-up, Realtek wifi dongle, Ubuntu 16.04 and same recent kernel upgrade, and my wifi works fine. So there has to be another reason for your wifi failure. Output for `sudo lshw -C network` needed.

Comment: Is that all? No wonder your wifi does not work. You're not even set up for wifi according to that output. That shows just the ethernet setup.  Have you checked with your router that your wireless configuration still exists?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

You should be all set.